# Error:Cannot find module 'shrink-ray', tried installing hitting another error

Tags: node.js

node version is 8.9.4. (project requirement)

npm version is 5.6.0.

This is an existing project, and after installing node modules, when i try `npm start`, i hit this error. So i tried `npm install shrink-ray`. It throws the following error. I also tried to install the windows-build-tools, it still does'nt work. I have been stuck in this part for over a day now.

I have attached my system variable information as well for python variable.
It still throws the same error that it can't find my python exe while it works in my command line when i execute `python --version`. [enter image description here]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhZER.png

````
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(403): https://node-zopfli.s3.amazonaws.com/Release/zopfli-v1.4.0-node-v57-win32-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for node-zopfli@1.4.0 and node@8.9.4 (node-v57 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "D:\Library\Python\Python27\python.exe", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19044
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\Users\\krrajesh\\Project\\ahcom-pixel\\node_modules\\node-zopfli\\lib\\binding\\node-v57-win32-x64\\zopfli.node" "--module_name=zopfli" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\krrajesh\\Project\\ahcom-pixel\\node_modules\\node-zopfli\\lib\\binding\\node-v57-win32-x64" "--python=D:\\Library\\Python\\Python27\\python.exe" "--msvs_version=2017"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\krrajesh\Project\ahcom-pixel\node_modules\node-zopfli
gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\krrajesh\Project\ahcom-pixel\node_modules\node-zopfli\lib\binding\node-v57-win32-x64\zopfli.node --module_name=zopfli --module_path=C:\Users\krrajesh\Project\ahcom-pixel\node_modules\node-zopfli\lib\binding\node-v57-win32-x64 --python=D:\Library\Python\Python27\python.exe --msvs_version=2017' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\krrajesh\Project\ahcom-pixel\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19044
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\krrajesh\\Project\\ahcom-pixel\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\krrajesh\Project\ahcom-pixel\node_modules\node-zopfli
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.4
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.39
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\krrajesh\Project\ahcom-pixel\node_modules\node-zopfli\lib\binding\node-v57-win32-x64\zopfli.node --module_name=zopfli --module_path=C:\Users\krrajesh\Project\ahcom-pixel\node_modules\node-zopfli\lib\binding\node-v57-win32-x64 --python=D:\Library\Python\Python27\python.exe --msvs_version=2017' (1)
npm WARN jest-config@26.6.3 requires a peer of ts-node@>=9.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN jsdom@16.7.0 requires a peer of canvas@^2.5.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-addons-test-utils@15.6.2 requires a peer of react-dom@^15.4.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN slick-carousel@1.8.1 requires a peer of jquery@>=1.8.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ws@7.5.7 requires a peer of bufferutil@^4.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ws@7.5.7 requires a peer of utf-8-validate@^5.0.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ahcom-re-redesign@2.4.0 No repository field.
npm WARN ahcom-re-redesign@2.4.0 No license field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules\jest-haste-map\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-zopfli@1.4.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-zopfli@1.4.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\krrajesh\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-02-16T04_40_42_505Z-debug.log```
````

Answer (score 0):

This also happens in

- node 14
- node 12
- node 10

Seems that the guy who developed node-zopfli was trying to get attention with a 403 error